# How do I remove U posts?

Tags: post, demolition, gardening

I drove a 7 foot long [metal U post](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Blue-Hawk-Common-5-in-x-6-ft-Actual-0-6-in-x-5-in-x-6-ft-Powder-Coated-Steel-Garden-Fence-U-post-Post/4780967) into the ground about two feet with a post driver. It is now embedded in the ground beyond my ability to pull it out by hand.

When the time comes to remove the post from the ground, what tool do I need to pull it out, with force greater than I can produce with my arms alone? The post driver I have only works downward, it doesn't have a way to exert an upward force.

I note that "T post pullers" are available, but this is not a "T" post but a "U" post. It doesn't have quite the same studs as a "T" post, so I am not sure if a T post puller would work on it or would be safe to try.

There is a special "U post puller" product available from a company called JackJaw, but it seems to be a specialty product for traffic engineers, not the complement of the $45 post driver I got to go with the posts.

Comment: The real way is to rent a 25 ton excavator to pull it out.  Or wrap a chain around it and use almost any jack.  Long old style car jacks will work faster.

Comment: Soaking/flooding the ground around the post will help a lot to pull by hand.

Comment: Better yet, use the hose stream to hydro-excavate beside the post.

Comment: A 1/2” to hose fitting adapter and a 3’ length of threaded PVC pipe will cost $5 or so and makes a great water jet. Use additional pipe pieces when you want to run something under a sidewalk or driveway.

Comment: Drill a hole in the post, get a long 2x4 with a big nail driven in the end to use as a lever, and use a concrete block as a fulcrum?

Answer (score 4):

Driven in 2 feet? One post? A **shovel** is the appropriate tool. Dig down about a foot and start wiggling the post. Dig a bit more if it won't wiggle.

50 posts? **Then** you might want a puller of some sort. As far as I recall my T-post puller has a slot that can be used to anchor a chain loop for pulling things other than actual T posts.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the ground isn't frozen a T post puller or jack should do the trick. There are simple lever models that use your muscle to pry it from the ground. The more expensive type use a post and the attachment ratchets up like an old time bumper jack. Which type to use depends on budget the number of posts to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Use a lever and some means of lashing. Specifically, I lever with a 2x4 and I lash with some chain. You might have other materials at hand that would serve as well.

Set a block on the ground so that the post stands between you and the block. Rest one end of the 2x4/lever on the block and position the lever a little below comfortable lifting height. Lash the lever to the post. Lift the lever.

That's the theory. There's lots of subtle tuning that makes the process work better. For example, the spacing between the block, the post, and your lifting point on the lever. When the block is near the post you'll get maximum gain of levering force but actually move the post only a small distance out of the ground. So start this way and as post movement becomes easier, move the block further from the post so as to get more post travel with each lever stroke.

Finding a lashing that won't slip on the post can be tricky. My favorite is the "clove hitch" which you can find documented on many knot-tying sites.